# noVNC Multiple Localhost Servers

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, novnc

Ive got 4 dev VMs for four projects (all VMware Player VMs w/ubuntu 15.04 host) where each is running VNC (ports 5900, 5901, 5902, 5903) respectively.

I downloaded noVNC and saved to /var/www/html (my apache2 server on same host). Based on the ReadMe I then ran on my terminal

```
 ./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900
```

I received a missing websockify error, so [downloaded](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) it and placed it into the util folder. I then ran the same command and it worked! The terminal told me to Navigate to a url and sure enough I could control my VM.

However -- I'm wondering how can I use noVnc to access all 4 VM's? Is there some simple way to extend the port to a range like in iptables or firewalld?

```
./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900-5903
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, Ill answer for myself here in case it helps someone in the future...

First, create a token file where each line has a nickname, ip address, and port.

I created a file named token.list where each line looks like:

```
localhostnickname1: localhost:5900
localhostnickname2: localhost:5901
...
```

Then I use my terminal to go into the websockify folder so I can see the **run** file. I issue it the command:

```
./run --web /path/to/noVNC --target-config /path/to/token.list localhost:6080
```

Finally, I open my web browser and go to :

```
http://localhost:6080/vnc_auto.html?path=?token=localhostnickname1
```

Where localhost1 is the nickname of my first server on the first line of token.list

[This link](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/issues/522) was my reference. If you want to serve this outside of localhost -- change the parameter localhost:8060 from localhost to an IP

Comment: Thank you. This helps me a lot